# ASP.Net 4.0 , Update Panel.. causing flicker of whole webpage

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, updatepanel

I have made a web site, a chatting application,... On a webpage independent of Master page, i added a Ajax Update Panel, In the update panel i added a timer , a memo, and a hidden field,..
Its working but causing the whole webpage to flicker,   that has made my approach ugly..
Please any programmer help me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you use a text box to show the chat ? remove it and use a div, maybe is not working correct. Anyway if you do not show us the code, how to find the real reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the related code segments?  Without that, it is difficult to guess what the problem is.

Page flicker could be:

- Page load firing twice in update
- Timer firing when not intended

  The list goes on...

If you are unable to post the code, I would troubleshoot by removing everything but the core functionality until you can get the flicker to stop then add pieces back in.  That is really all I can offer you without the code.